# replacing values with condition from tble

Tags: r

creating sub function to replace even values with NA

```
library(expss)
library(dplyr)

t1 <- structure(list(row_labels = c("c3|Mean", "c3|Median", "c3|75th Perc.75%", 
"c3|Valid N"), `#Total` = c(21.1666666666667, 17.5, 27.75, 6), 
    `Dept 1` = c(21.6, 16, 33.5, 5), `Dept 2` = c(16, 16, 19, 
    2), `Dept 3` = c(33.5, 33.5, 45, 2), `Dept 4` = c(26.6666666666667, 
    22, 45, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("etable", 
"data.frame"))


#till now everything is working fine
```

Comment: Please shorten your code to a minimal amount, so your issue becomes visible at a glance. It is hard to follow.

Comment: Note you don't need `which()` in  `which(grepl(...))`  in the `x[i, j] <- value` logic i and j can also both logical vectors.

Comment: @s_baldur i am modifying my function after t1 is generated so i have to make it dynamic, i am getting duplicate subscripts for column error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

t1 %>%
  # Transpose data frame.
  pivot_longer(names_to = "col", values_to = "value", cols = !row_labels) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row_labels, values_from = value) %>%
  # Apply logic.
  mutate(
    `c3|Mean` = ifelse(`c3|Valid N` <= 4, NA, `c3|Mean`),
    `c3|Median` = ifelse(`c3|Valid N` <= 4, NA, `c3|Median`),
    `c3|75th Perc.75%` = ifelse(`c3|Valid N` <= 5, NA, `c3|75th Perc.75%`),
  ) %>%
  # Transpose back again.
  pivot_longer(names_to = "row_labels", values_to = "value", cols = !col) %>%
  # Replace NA with "--".
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(value), "--", value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value)
```

The output is

```
  row_labels       `#Total` `Dept 1` `Dept 2` `Dept 3` `Dept 4`
  <chr>            <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 c3|Mean          21.2     21.6     --       --       --      
2 c3|Median        17.5     16       --       --       --      
3 c3|75th Perc.75% 27.8     --       --       --       --      
4 c3|Valid N       6        5        2        2        3
```

This approach essentially transposes the data frame. Once transposed the logic is easier to apply (albeit not very pretty due to the column names). Rather than replacing with `"--"` I prefer to replace with `NA`s. Then you transpose it back again, replacing the `NA`s with `"--"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-liner with `lapply`:

```
library(expss)

t1 <- structure(list(row_labels = c("c3|Mean", "c3|Median", "c3|75th Perc.75%", 
"c3|Valid N"), `#Total` = c(21.1666666666667, 17.5, 27.75, 6), 
`Dept 1` = c(21.6, 16, 33.5, 5), `Dept 2` = c(16, 16, 19, 
2), `Dept 3` = c(33.5, 33.5, 45, 2), `Dept 4` = c(26.6666666666667, 
22, 45, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("etable", 
"data.frame"))


t1[,-1] = lapply(t1[,-1], \(x) if(x[length(x)]<4) { x[-length(x)] = '--'; x} else x)
t1

 # |    |               | #Total | Dept 1 | Dept 2 | Dept 3 | Dept 4 |
 # | -- | ------------- | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ | ------ |
 # | c3 |          Mean |   21.2 |   21.6 |     -- |     -- |     -- |
 # |    |        Median |   17.5 |   16.0 |     -- |     -- |     -- |
 # |    | 75th Perc.75% |   27.8 |   33.5 |     -- |     -- |     -- |
 # |    |       Valid N |    6.0 |    5.0 |      2 |      2 |      3 |
```